# JavaScript DOM making server request

Tags: javascript, dom

When I'm loading the page without the following js code it runs perfectly, but when I'm creating the html elements using DOM it some how it makes server request with same page url,

```
      const isHideVariants = document.querySelector("#hidevariants");
      const vehiclesList = document.querySelector(".brand-vehicles-list");

      let vehicles = <%- JSON.stringify(vehicles) %>;

      displayVehicles();

      function displayVehicles() {
        clearVehicles();
        vehicles.forEach((vehicle) => {
          const anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
          const img = document.createElement("img");
          const p = document.createElement("p");
          anchorTag.href = `/vehicles/${vehicle._id}`;
          anchorTag.classList.add("brand-vehicle");
          img.src = vehicle.thumbnail;
          img.alt = "vehicle thumbnail";
          p.textContent = vehicle.name;
          anchorTag.appendChild(img);
          anchorTag.appendChild(p);
          vehiclesList.appendChild(anchorTag);
        });
      }

      function clearVehicles() {
        while (vehiclesList.firstChild) {
          vehiclesList.removeChild(vehiclesList.firstChild);
        }
      }
```

I've tested the code when I comment the js DOM code then it was not making any other server requests

This is first request

```
GET /brands/dodge 200 2109.074 ms - 16952
```

this is second request which is triggered when I'm creating html DOM element

```
GET /brands/undefined 200 8297.877 ms - 16781
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This GET request was sent by the `src` attribute of `<img>` tag. And the value of `src` is `undefined`. Which means the `vehicle.thumbnail` is `undefined` in your code.

See [how src attribute of img tag is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953792/how-src-attribute-of-img-tag-is-executed)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying for a day, It means no matter if someone is an expert at programming, it still needs help from a team, thanks to Stackoverfolow for such a wonderful community.